# Footnote is split between the two columns of my document

Tags: spacing

The title says it all. It looks kind of awkward in my opinion. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}



 Next, I introduce the data I used for this study, the Standard and Poor's Execucomp, arguably the golden standard for CEO compensation data\footnote{Florin, Hallock, and Webber (2010) hold that ``ExecuComp (Executive
    Compensation data base) is produced by Standard and Poor’s Corporation and is surely the
    most widely used source of data for research on executive pay by academics.''}, and The Center for Research in Securities Prices (CRSP) data sets. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So what do you want the footnote to look like?

Comment: @Mico does this look standard to you? I figured it would be more aesthetically pleasing if it were all on underneath the right hand column

Comment: But that would create a "hole" at the bottom of the left-hand column, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Mico I suppose so

Comment: The only thing that might bother me about the split footnote is that the footnote material on the right isn't aligned fully along the bottom edge of the textblock. This can be fixed by loading the `footmisc` package with the option `bottom`.

Comment: @Mico I know how to load packages, but how do I use the option?

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted?

Comment: @Mico , yes I had liked it and accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think of the following options:

- Write fewer footnotes. Instead, place the material in the body of the text.
- Write only (really) short footnotes.
- If two preceding options aren't feasible, just get used to the idea that occasionally, longish footnotes will have to be broken across pages or (in the case of a two-column document) across columns. I honestly don't see what's supposed to be so "awkward". To improve the aesthetics, you may want to consider loading the `footmisc` package with the options `bottom` and `splitrule`. The `splitrule` option makes LaTeX draw a full-width rule on the page with the trailing footnote material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage[splitrule,bottom]{footmisc} % <-- new
\hyphenation{execu-comp}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]

 Next, I introduce the data I used for this study, the Standard and Poor's ExecuComp, arguably the gold standard for CEO compensation data,\footnote{Florin, Hallock, and Webber (2010) hold that ``ExecuComp (Executive
    Compensation data base) is produced by Standard and Poor’s Corporation and is surely the
    most widely used source of data for research on executive pay by academics.''} and The Center for Research in Securities Prices (CRSP) data sets. 

\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```